Transversality condition in calculus of Variations
Maximize the integral $\int_0^1\left(-\dot{x}^2-4 x^2+12 \dot{x} e^t\right) d t$ with respect to functions $x(t)$, satisfying the initial condition $x(0)=-2$ and the terminal condition
a) $x(1) \geq-10$,
b) $x(1) \leq-10$.
The Solution is as follows.
Define $F$ to be the integrand of the integral we are trying to maximize. That is,
$$
\begin{aligned}
& F(t, x, \dot{x})=-\dot{x}^2-4 x^2+12 \dot{x} e^t \\
& \partial_x F=-8 x, \partial_x F=-2 \dot{x}+12 e^t
\end{aligned}
$$
Euler-Lagrange Equations becomes
$$
\ddot{x}-4 x=6 e^t
$$
The solution to the above is $x(t)=C_1 e^{2 t}+C_2 e^{-2 t}-2 e^t$
Initial condition $x(0)=C_1+C_2-2=-2 \Rightarrow C_1=-C_2$
Transversality condition:
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \left.\partial_{\dot{x}} F\right|_{t=1}=-2 \dot{x}(1)+12 e=0 \Rightarrow \dot{x}(1)=6 e \\
\Rightarrow & 2 C_1 e^2-2 C_2 e^{-2}-2 e=6 e \\
& 2 C_1\left(e^2+e^{-2}\right)=8 e \Rightarrow C_1=-C_2=\frac{4 e}{e^2+e^{-2}}=\frac{2 e}{\cosh (2)} \\
& x(t)=4 e \frac{\sinh (2 t)}{\cosh (2)}-2 e^t \\
& x(1)=2 e-\frac{8 e}{1+e^4}
\end{aligned}
$$
Since $F$ is concave in $(x, i)$, this is the solution in case (a).
In case (b), we solve the Euler-Lagrange equation with $X(1)=-10$.
From previous computations:
$$
\begin{aligned}
& x(t)=2 C_1 \sinh (2 t)-2 e^t \\
& x(1)=2 C_1 \sinh (2)-2 e=-10 \\
& \Rightarrow C_1=\frac{e-5}{\sinh (2)} \\
& \Rightarrow x(t)=2(e-5) \frac{\sinh (2 t)}{\sinh (2)}-2 e^t
\end{aligned}
$$
My questions are

In part (a) how did they obtain the transversality condition and is there a good reference in this topic

Why do they not need the transversality condition in part (b).



Your calculus of variations problem touches upon the topic of inequality constraints on either initial or terminal points or both (please, refer to Part I Section 12 of Kamien & Schwartz (2000)). Specifically, in both a) and b) parts of the question, we are dealing with $x(t_1) \leq a$ or $x(t_1) \geq a$ where $a$ is a constant. Before we move straight to the solution, let’s introduce some criteria regarding inequality constraints on endpoints for a maximization problem:

When $x(t_1) \leq a$: $(x_1-a)F_{x’}(t_1)=0$; $F_{x’}(t_1) \geq 0$
When $x(t_1) \geq a$: $(x_1-a)F_{x’}(t_1)=0$; $F_{x’}(t_1) \leq 0$

The transversatility condition that you are asking comes from a general case of the total first-order differentiation of the integrand with all endpoints set to be free:
$$\delta J= J-J^{*}=( F(t_{1}) -F_{x’}( t_{1}) x’( t_{1})) \delta t_{1}-(F(t_{0}) -F_{x’}( t_{0}) x’( t_{0})) \delta t_{0}+ F_{x’}( t_{1}) \delta x_{1}-F_{x’}( t_{0}) \delta x_{0}
+\int ^{t_{1}}_{t_{0}}h\left( F_{x}-\dfrac{\partial F_{x’}}{\partial t}\right) dt \leq 0$$
In maximization problem, any alternative to the optimal solution yields lower value, so that’s why $\delta J \leq 0$. Since in your particular problem, only $x(t_1)$ is constrained and that $(t_0, t_1,x(t_0))$ are known, and for optimality, the Euler equation must hold, the total first order differentiation simplifies to:
$$\delta J= F_{x’}( t_{1}) \delta x_{1} \leq 0$$
Now here is an interesting part for $x \leq a$:

When $x<a$, $\delta x_1$ can be either positive or negative, so to guarantee an inequality, $F_{x’}( t_{1}) $ must be zero.
When $x=a$, $\delta x_1 \leq 0$ and therefore, $F_{x’}( t_{1}) \geq 0$ must hold.

Combine the above two criteria to get the maximization criteria when terminal endpoint has the restriction $x \leq a$. For $x \geq a$ you use the same logic to derive the corresponding criteria.
As for the solutions:

The above explanation must give you a good idea on why the original solution uses that particular transversatility condition
Because in part a the original solution has already checked the case for $F_{x’}( t_{1}) = 0$, in part b it is now checking for $(x_1-a)=0$. In this case, obviously all your border conditions are set, so you only use border conditions to calculate Euler Equation coefficients and you are done, no need for transversatility.

I find the original solution to be incomplete since it omits the procedures for checking for either $F_{x’}(t_1) \geq 0$ or $F_{x’}(t_1) \leq 0 $. I hope my answer fully answers your question.
